# pygame.display.update(); pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Here is my **underdeveloped pygame ping-pong game**, but my **sprites**(player&opponent) **ain't moving**, on giving a keyboard input. And when I quit the program, it yells an **error** `pygame.error: video system not initialized`. My pygame is the latest 1.9.6 version with all the files up-to-daee. However, I am certain that `pygame.display` is generating this error, but I even tried `pygame.display.init()` and that too didn't worked :(

```
import pygame

# Initialization
pygame.init()
# Screen, Caption and Icon
width = 800
height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('PyGame')
icon = pygame.image.load('ping-pong.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
# Create Rects
player = pygame.Rect((5, 230), (10, 120))
opponent = pygame.Rect((785, 230), (10, 120))
# Game Variables
playerY_change = 0
opponentY_change = 0

game_over = False
while not game_over:
    # Coloring the Screen
    screen.fill((27, 35, 43))
    # Draw Rects
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), player)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), opponent)
    # Managing Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.type == pygame.K_UP:
                opponentY_change -= 3
            if event.type == pygame.K_DOWN:
                opponentY_change += 3
            if event.type == pygame.K_w:
                playerY_change -= 3
            if event.type == pygame.K_s:
                playerY_change += 3
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (event.type == pygame.K_UP) or (event.type == pygame.K_DOWN):
                opponentY_change = 0
            if (event.type == pygame.K_w) or (event.type == pygame.K_s):
                playerY_change = 0

    # Moving my sprites
    player.y += playerY_change
    opponent.y += opponentY_change
    # Updating the screen on every iter of loop
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you have two different problems :

First the movement is not working because to differentiate the keys, you use `event.type` to compare where it should be `event.key`. Try with for example :

```
if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
   opponentY_change -= 3
```

The other problem is that when the game is over, you use `pygame.quit()` but later on the loop, you use `pygame.display.update()`. You should put the display update at the **beginning** of the loop.